# parse.com selecting from join table

Tags: join, parse-platform

Just wondering am I doing this correctly or is there a better way.

I have 3 tables, **Game, User and UserGame**. The UserGame is a join table has pointers to both Game and User tables.

The following script returns all the games that the user has joined.

```
var Game = Parse.Object.extend("Game");
var UserGame = Parse.Object.extend("UserGame");

var innerQuery = new Parse.Query(Game);

var query = new Parse.Query(UserGame);
query.equalTo("user", user);
query.matchesQuery("game", innerQuery);
query.include("game");
query.find({
```

I am now trying to return the games that the user has not joined. I tried the reverse of the above query but it does not work. Any ideas?

Also is there a better solution than using the join table above, should I just add a list of game pointers to the user table?

Answer (score 2):

This is userful (and not easily accessible from the website)

https://parse.com/docs/js/symbols/Parse.Query.html

What you're trying to do seems like a good usecase of `.noContainerIn([results of the first query])` or `.doesNotMatchKeyInQuery`

`matchesKeyInQuery` in your first example seems simpler to use BTW

Answer (score 1):

I have used a table that has two pointers inside it too.I'm going to explain what I did simplified, and adpating it to your case:

1.Build a query with your object Game,to get an array of all games that exists in this table:

```
var Game = Parse.Object.extend("Game");
    var query = new Parse.Query(Game);
    query.find({
      success: function(arrayGames) { 
       //store this array to manage later
      },
      error: function(user, error) {
            alert("There is not stored games");
            }
    });
```

2. Get the user you want to compare to this games stored that points in the table UserGame, and make a Query for each element of the previous got array:

```
var UserGame = Parse.Object.extend("UserGame");
    var query = new Parse.Query(UserGame);
var currentUser = Parse.User.current();
var currentGame;
for(var i=0; i<arrayGames.length ;i++){
 currentGame=arrayGames[i];
 query.equalTo("Game", currentGame);
 query.notEqualTo("User", currentUser);
  query.find({
      success: function(foundGames) {
      //you have got an array with the games not joined to this user 
      },
       error: function(user, error) {
            alert("There are not joined games ");
                }
    });
}
```

Hope it helps, ask me if you need more details ;)